# BEX error when trying to compile/run a program using Intellij IDEA

Tags: windows-7, crash, intellij-idea

*I already asked [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28879132/intellij-idea-crashes-when-trying-to-compile-run-a-program/28881510), but was told to better ask it here.*

---

I wanted to try out IDEA because I want to move away from Eclipse. However, every time I try to build or run code from inside IDEA, it just crashes with no error message. The only information I get is from Windows itself:

```html
Problemsignatur (Problem signature):
  Problemereignisname (Problem event name): BEX
  Anwendungsname (Application name):    idea.exe
  Anwendungsversion (Application version):  14.0.3.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel (Application timestamp):    5437b4c8
  Fehlermodulname (Error module name):  SDHook32.dll
  Fehlermodulversion (Error module version):    2.3.39.2
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel (Error module timestamp):  535a5137
  Ausnahmeoffset (Exception offset):    00025942
  Ausnahmecode (Exception code):    c0000417
  Ausnahmedaten (Exception data):   00000000
  Betriebsystemversion (Operating system version):  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Gebietsschema-ID (Area schema ID):    3079
  Zusatzinformation 1 (Additional information 1):   6ec5
  Zusatzinformation 2 (Additional information 2):   6ec5ee19c106a54dd0feced4a6ea5c17
  Zusatzinformation 3 (Additional information 3):   633b
  Zusatzinformation 4 (Additional information 4):   633bad3421e95a8b92bd60a69d1ca25c
```

Sorry that it is in German. I tried to translate the keys into English but don't know if they actually match the English version of the error message. I'm running Windows 7 64-bit; error happens with both 32-bit and 64-bit version of IDEA. Used JDK is 1.8.0_20 (also 64-bit).

I tried to disable DEP for IDEA, but Windows just tells me the following:

> This program must run with data execution protection (DEP) enabled.
>   You cannot turn off DEP for this program.

Turning off DEP entirely doesn't seem like a good idea to me. Any suggestions how I could try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fehlermodulname (Error module name): SDHook32.dll
```

The `SDHook32.dll` sounds like you use `Spybot - Search & Destroy`. Try to uninstall this tool and look if this fixes your issue.

Comment: This is indeed a Spybot S&D problem. Disabling Spybot's Live Protection did the trick for now. Thanks!

Comment: ok, accept the reply to "close" the topic.